# Failed to restart tomact8.service: Unit tomact8.service not found

Tags: tomcat8

After installing Tomcat 8 when I run *systemctl restart tomact8*  error will show *Failed to restart tomact8.service: Unit tomact8.service not found.* 
what shoud i do tell me

Answer (score 0):

Typo...

`tomact8` should be changed to:

`tomcat8`